# How to disallow network file access even for domain administrators? Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have a computer in domain and i want to disallow access to my files over network (eg. by path `\\mycomputer\c$`) for all users even for domain aministrator. Or if there is way to simply control this access?

Comment: Are you interested in other shares like `\\mycomputer\ExampleShare` or just the ones ending in `$`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any solution you can perform will be temporary, however here are some options.

1. [Disable Administrative Shares entirely](http://www.petri.co.il/disable_administrative_shares.htm) (A domain admin can re-enable them via GPO)
2. [Set Deny file permissions](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-permissions-allow.htm) for your drive. You can't change permission on the share it self, but you can change the permissions of what the share points to. (A domain admin can remove the Deny right via GPO)
3. Store the information you don't want seen on a removable drive, remove it when not in use. (A domain admin could connect to it while it is plugged in)

If you are on a domain and the machine you are using was provided by the company they are the legal owners of that machine and have a right to everything on that machine.

If you are doing something that you don't want your domain admin to find, don't do it on domain attached computer.

Comment: This seems to be good for start

Answer (score 0):

If you're an administrator of that computer, you can turn off sharing by right-clicking on the share resource and click Properties then click the Sharing tab.  But bear in mind, the Domain Admin or Group Policy over the network have the ability to turn that back on.

Comment: Also, it comes back when you reboot.